# How to include Group cover photo in Group Info Endpoint on Facebook Graph API

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have the following endpoint to retrieve the details of a Facebook group via its id

```
let groupInfoUrl = `https://graph.facebook.com/${group_id}?access_token=${accessToken}`;
```

Below is an example of the response I got:

```
{
  "name": "Group Name",
  "privacy": "OPEN",
  "id": "012345678901234"
}
```

How can I make the response to also include the Group Cover photo or icon?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to add `fields=cover` to your query:

```
let groupInfoUrl = `https://graph.facebook.com/${group_id}?fields=cover&access_token=${accessToken}`;
```